# image is not being displayed in the html page

Tags: javascript

This JS code failed to show the image, instead it gives the string [object HTMLImageElement].
How can it be fixed so that it shows the image in this location? Thanks

```
let signature = $('canvas.signature').get(0).toDataURL(); //earlier in the code

let w = window.open();
let doc = w.document;
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
let sigImg = new Image();
sigImg.src = signature;
let nodes = doc.querySelectorAll('td.Label');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var item = nodes[i];
  if (item.textContent === "User's signature:") {
    item.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = sigImg; //<--- failed to show the image
  }
}
```

**edit**
The reason I did not use
`item.nextElementSibling.appendChild(sigImg);`
is because I wanted to replace the content of the `td` element with the image.
but even with this solution, I get a small icon, which when right click and open in new page, I get (This site can’t be reached).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this

```
item.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = sigImg;
```

... change to

```
item.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = ''; // clear contents
item.nextElementSibling.appendChild(sigImg);
```

sigImg is an object, you'll find you get [object Object] displayed instead with your code, I assume

Comment: oh, you want to replace the content of nextElementSibling?